# Set width of jQuery Tipsy bubble

Tags: jquery, width, tipsy

I'm using this plugin: http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/#options

Is there a way (preferably via CSS or else via jQuery) to set the width of the the popup bubble?

I'm applying tipsy on a link like so:

```
$('#linktip').tipsy({ html: true, opacity: 1.0 });

<a href="" id="linktip" class="help" original-title='<asp:Literal ID="Literalfd19" Text="<%$Resources:pastelink %>" runat="server"/>'><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i></a>
```

Comment: The jQuery plugin you are using does calculation for width `var actualWidth = $tip[0].offsetWidth,
                    actualHeight = $tip[0].offsetHeight,
                    gravity = maybeCall(this.options.gravity, this.$element[0]);`

Comment: Thank you. So how would I configure my call exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open tipsy.css and you will see line

```
.tipsy-inner { padding: 5px 8px 4px 8px; background-color: black; color: white; max-width: 200px; text-align: center; }
```

See there is a `max-width` which set to `200px`

Comment: Thanks! And any idea why the `opacity :1.0` property I set seems to be ignored? I keep getting a transparent bubble...

Comment: the opacity option is okay. maybe your other css does effect of the transparency?

Comment: the reason is because tipsy sets the opacity on the `style` attribute which trumps the CSS. Use `opacity:1 !important;` or within your tipsy config, set `opacity: 1`